# Different output, simple question

Tags: algebra

I found a slightly different output than what was expected in a book.

```
DefSumMod[10]
G={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}    
CircleGraph[G,Add[1]]
```

Why is the tracing directed from 9 toward the center? Or is it a different version of *Mathematica*?

[image: Display of the last code]

Comment: I do not have DefSumMod in version 10.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: These are commands from a package used by the book. Refer to the instructions there...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is in regards to a third-party *Mathematica* package for a text and not intrinsic *Mathematica* functionality.

Comment: What book? What is `DefSumMod`? What version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download latest package from [here](http://www.crcpress.com/downloads/C4521/C4521_Download_Files.zip)

Works fine for me (MMA 9.x):

```
DefSumMod[10]
G = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
CircleGraph[G, Add[1]]
```

[image]

Make sure you've not accidentally set some global symbol that might interfere with the package...